# how to activate motion shake after the user has pressed a button?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, button, motion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i put a void(shake gesture) inside a IBAction(button)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264989/how-do-i-put-a-voidshake-gesture-inside-a-ibactionbutton)

Hello I am creating a app, and I need help. I have asked this question 2 times before but I am not getting the right answer, it either docent work or the person dosen't realise that I am a total beginner. So before answering please explain the answer because I am very new to Xcode. So I have a button saying play, and currently when you click on it a animation appears smoothly and then ends. What I need to change is when the user press's play, a label saying shake the device to start. Then when the user shake's the device the label disappears and the animation plays and end, this is what I have so far in my viewcontroller.m file:

```
-(IBAction)startanimation {





animation.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame0.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame8.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame9.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame10.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame11.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame12.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame13.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame14.png"], 
                                nil];

    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    animation.animationDuration = 1;
    [animation startAnimating];



}
```

By the way, the IBAction:startanimation is the action when the user press's the button 'play'

Please consider I am a beginner to coding, and if you have any questions feel free to ask, THanks!

Answer (score 2):

Method

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

you just use this code:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
    //Your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your header file (.h)

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    BOOL canStartAnimation;
}
```

change start animation too

```
-(IBAction)startanimation 
{
    canStartAnimation = YES;
    label.text = @"shake to animate";
}
```

Add this function

```
-(void) doTheAnimation {
    animation.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame0.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame8.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame9.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame10.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame11.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame12.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame13.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame14.png"], 
                                nil];

    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    animation.animationDuration = 1;
    [animation startAnimating];   
    label.text = @"";
}
```

Add the motionBegan

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake && canStartAnimation) {
        [self doTheAnimation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your help, i have tried this on a test Xcode project and I think i have done it wrong but I am not sure, is their anyway I could email the test Xcode, then you could check why it's not doing what I need it to do?? :) thanks